# Switched from UILabel to UIButton. Text disappears

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel

I just switched from a `UILabel` to `UIButton`, intending to use the button's `titleLabel` property to display the information formerly displayed in the label replaced by the button.

Problem is, the text doesn't show up. I've checked to see if the button itself (normally with a transparent background, changed to red to check) is appearing, and it is, but the text isn't there. Here's a sample of the relevant code, which is identical to the original (working) code from the label, changing only lines like:

```
UILabel *firstLabel;

(...)

firstLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

to:

```
UIButton *firstLabel;

(...)

firstLabel.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Here's a full chunk for clarity:

```
         firstLabel.frame = CGRectMake(thisRiser.bounds.origin.x, thisRiser.frame.size.height -focusBarEndHeight - 55, barWidth, 60);
         firstLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
         firstLabel.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
         firstLabel.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%.2f%%\nTime--%@",focusItemName,focusItemPercent,actualDurationFocusItem];
         [firstLabel.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
         firstLabel.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
         firstLabel.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
         [firstLabel setHidden:NO];
```

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Thanks!

**UPDATE --
This may be related to a known bug!**

Many thanks to the responders below. I implemented the first recommended fix, which resolved my initial problem, so my text now appears in the label. However, the UIControlStateHighlighted and UIControlStateSelected don't work.

For example, this code produces no discernible effect to the text when clicked:

```
firstLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[firstLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[firstLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[firstLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

After searching around SO for a while, I'm coming to the conclusion that there is a bug (at least in iOS 7) that prevents proper functioning of these methods. Unfortunately, I'm not smart enough to provide more detailed information, but plenty of recent posts point to a major problem in this area of UIControl.

I'll be ecstatic to be proven wrong, because I'd like to use this functionality.

Comment: Did you try `–setTitle:forState:` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIButton` responds to different messages, you can use the button state to change its title.

You can set the title like this;

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setTitle:@"Title goes here" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

See Control State: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState

Comment: OK--your suggested code works great! However, a new problem arises. I want the text color to change when the user taps the label (in addition to sending to a new view controller where detail will be displayed). I've tried                  `[firstLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                 [firstLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];`, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

To set a title in an `UIButton`, you have to init the button:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 60, 20)];
```

and then use:

```
[button setTitle:@"text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

where you **must specific** the control state (*highlighted*, *selected*, etc.)

Comment: You should select your right answer to close the ticket opened first of all. Then we can also see other stuff.

Comment: In any case the code has not bug..tested now and work properly. What is your problem? You set the color to white so maybe you don't see it because is on a white background? i don't know...where did you put that code?

Comment: You're right, Mateo. I should have separated the two problems. I'll post the other problem in a new question.

Comment: Hi already reply to your question here..your code doesnt have problem. I asked you, where do you use that code..in what point. So in any case, set the right answer please.

Comment: I put the code in the same function that created the button(s). I must be misunderstanding something critical. Can you show the code you used to test it, or tell me where you put it?

Comment: i simply did the same your test putting the code in viewDidLoad:

`UIButton *firstLabel = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 100, 50)];
    [firstLabel setTitle:@"TITLE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    firstLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [firstLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [firstLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [firstLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor orangeColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.view addSubview:firstLabel];`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52552/discussion-between-tim-jones-and-matteo-gobbi)

Answer (score 0):

try for example,

```
UIButton *firstLabel = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
firstLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, 100, 50); //set the frame
[firstLabel setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[firstLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];//for test
[firstLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //it will always displays green for normal
[firstLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];//if u touch it text changed to white instantly
[firstLabel setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];//if touch it and hold it shows white color
```

Comment: I've tried this--with variations--to no avail. I've got another issue (a linker error) that I'm tracking down, but will return to this shortly. Thanks!